# how to launch an app from a python function

Tags: python, tkinter

So i'm trying to launch an app from a python function and for some reason it's not working

file with function
pages.py:

```
import platform as pf
import tkinter as tk

def pge1() :
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title('test mini app')
    win.mainloop()
```

where function is called
main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import platform as pf
import pages as pgs

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
       *bttn = tk.Button( text="mini app", command=pgs.pge1() )
       bttn.pack()*
       os = tk.Label(self, text = 'your os type is : ' + pf.system() )
       os.pack()
       version = tk.Label(self, text= 'your os verison is : ' + pf.version() )
       version.pack()
       processor = tk.Label(self, text='your processor is : ' + pf.processor() )
       processor.pack()
```

this isn't the whole file because it's big but it's

I was trying to open an tkinter app from a function I hoped it would work but it deleted the rest of the main app except the button

Comment: Does main.py already create a tkinter `Tk()` object somewhere that you haven't included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem right, removing the `()` from your command will make it work.

```
bttn = tk.Button( text="mini app", command=pgs.pge1)
```

This is because if you include the parens, Python will end up calling that function when creating the button as opposed to only when you click the button.  If you need to include parens, use a lambda function:

```
bttn = tk.Button( text="mini app", command=lambda: pgs.pge1())
```

You should also probably be using `Toplevel()` if you intend for the second window to be a popup window instead of `Tk()` in your `pages.py`.

```
def pge1() :
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.title('test mini app')
    win.mainloop()
```